# Python port scanner only port 80 open

Tags: python, port-scanning

When I run my python port scanner I only ever see port 80 open, regardless of the IP or website. I tested the code on testphp.vulnweb.com so I expected more than just port 80 open.

```
import socket
from IPy import IP

def scan(target):
    converted_ip = check_ip(target)
    print('\n' + '[-_0 Scanning Target] ' + str(target))
    for port in range(1, 100):
        scan_port(converted_ip, port)

def get_banner(s):
    return s.recv(1024)

def check_ip(ip):
    try:
        IP(ip)
        return(ip)
    except ValueError:
        return socket.gethostbyname(ip)

def scan_port(ipaddress, port):
    try:
        ## define a socket descriptor
        sock = socket.socket()
        sock.settimeout(0.5) ## in order to scan target faster, lose accuracy but gain time
        sock.connect((ipaddress, port))
        try:
            banner = get_banner(sock)
            print('[+] Open port' + str(port) + ' : ' + str(banner))
        except:
            print('[+] Open Port ' + str(port))
    except:
        pass


targets = input('[+] Enter Target/s To Scan (split multiple targets with ,): ')
if ',' in targets:
    for ip_add in targets.split(','):
        scan(ip_add.strip(' '))
else:
    scan(targets)
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are probably more ports open, but you check only from 1 to 100. Most ports used in the wild are higher than that.

```
for port in range(1, 100):
    scan_port(converted_ip, port)
```

From the top of my head, I only know 4 commonly used ports in this range. SSH (22), SMTP (25), DNS (53), and HTTP (80).

HTTPS for example is most of the time on 443. MySQL has by default 3306. Redis has 6379.

So you should at least check up to 10000, probably even higher. The highest port number allowed is 65535.

Comment: It usually doesn't make sense to scan beyond 32768.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, tried increasing the range but get the same result - only port 80 is ever shown as open. Is it possibly something to do with my VPN, or that I'm running through a virtual environment? I also tried removing the timeout code in case it was just a slow response but no good. The testphp.vulnweb.com site I think is supposed to return port 21, 22, 53 and 80 as open as its a testing website for portscanning.

Comment: @footos I would not necessarily expect those ports to be open. Maybe ssh but smtp and DNS are usually only open on mail and name server respectively. What was the range you checked?

Comment: I checked up to 10000 like you suggested. The website that I used to scan is supposed to show those ports open I think. Its like a testing page for portscanners. The course I'm following shows those ports as open in the material - but I can't contact the author to get more help and there's no q&a section or I would.